# Yii2 Accordion, how to make first tab inactive

Tags: yii2

```
echo Accordion::widget([
            'items' => [
                [
                    'header' => 'Section 1',
                    'content' => 'Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget...',
                    'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
                ],
                [
                    'header' => 'Section 2',
                    'headerOptions' => ['tag' => 'h3'],
                    'content' => 'Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus...',
                    'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
                ],
            ],
            'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
            'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'div'],
            'headerOptions' => ['tag' => 'h2'],
            'clientOptions' => ['collapsible' => true],
        ]);
```

Hi. First tab active by default, how to make first tab inactive? In the documentation I did not find information on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is add to options

```
'active' => false

'clientOptions' => ['collapsible' => true, 'active' => false],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the first tab inactive, and the second tab active, use

`'clientOptions' => ['active' => 1]`